# How to Notify the Web Application if any changes happen in the database in Asp.Net and Sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have database table which contains id ,agent name, status. if some body modifies the table in the data base automatically it should get identified byweb application.

When I am looking for the probability found sqlCachedependency , but i don't have permissions for that to test.

Just checking for another possibility some thing like ,
1)when ever table get modified, i am writing a trigger which will fetch the       changes.
2)now i would like to send the triggered changes automatically to Web application with out refreshing the page.

**Requirement is :** Instead of continuously monitoring the changes in the database, i want to notify my application, if any changes happens in the data base table, web page has to notified and it should update the changes automatically with out post back.

I am using Vs2013, sql server 2008R2

Any help/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you break down your question to specific requirement?
Like do you want to watch for specific value or table or multiples of them?

Comment: @ Pravin Deshmukh: separated .

Comment: The question is not clear as it is. What does `notify the web application` mean?  What do you want to happen when a table is modified? Are you asking how to notify one *client* t refresh its view view when some other client changes the underlying data? This is a completely different thing that has very little (<20%) to do with databases